# Stream audio file from Google Cloud Storage to iOS Firebase client app

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, stream, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Firebase with an iOS client app, and I need to stream an audio file from Google Cloud Storage. I know file streaming support exists in the Android SDK with the class: `StreamDownloadTask`, but I cannot find an equivalent in the iOS SDK.

1. Best scenario would be able to achieve this without intermediary server functions, so directly between the iOS client and GCS. Is this possible?
2. If not, I have a Node.js server that I can use. Should I use the `createReadStream` GCS API function and pipe that to the client? Or is there a better way?

Any advice on the optimal way to create a stream from a GCS audio file to an iOS app would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

*Firebase employee here*

There is not, in fact, any Cloud Storage streaming API for iOS in the same way that there is for Android.  If this is important to you, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) and explain why it's important for your particular case.